# How can I use this object of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a theme and I like to run some code for an element only if this element is visible in viewport of my browser. To achive that, I found this code, but I am not sure how can I use it:

```
$.fn.isOnScreen =   function()
{
    var win =   $(window);
    var viewport    =   {
        top  : win.scrollTop(),
        left : win.scrollLeft()
    };

    viewport.right  =   viewport.left   +   win.width();
    viewport.bottom =   viewport.top    +   win.height();

    var bounds      =   this.offset();

    bounds.right    =   bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom   =   bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
};
```

I have try this way:

```
$(this).isOnScreen().css('color', '#0AF');
```

But I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in my console.

Can somebody help me with this method, and how can I use it ?

Comment: have you tried using `$(this).css('color', '#0AF').isOnScreen();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `isOnScreen()` function you have there returns a boolean, not a jQuery object, so you cannot chain jQuery methods from it. Try this:

```
if ($(this).isOnScreen()) {
    $(this).css('color', '#OAF');
}
```

Also, I don't understand the point of changing the colour of something only while it's on screen - if it's off screen it can't be seen, so it will only ever be seen to be one colour.

Comment: what it basically do ``isOnScreen()``?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan let me try. Ehsan Sajjad, this method check if an element is in browser view port

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, that was !! Thanks, I will mark your answer correct in a few minutes. Thanks !! :)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad it checks if any part of the given element is within the bounds of the viewport. It's not a standard jQuery function.

Comment: its user defined in it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use first set the css using `.css()` which returns the current object and then use isOnscreen method that you wrote:

```
$(this).css('color', '#0AF').isOnScreen();
```

Comment: I don't think that is usefull this way, because I like to apply the css only if the element is on screen. In your case firstly I will set the color, and then I will check for the element position. Anyway, thanks for your response ! :)

Comment: This is incorrect. It will always set the colour, regardless of the screen position of the element.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: i totally agree to that if use want to filter first then this wont work. returning the object from onscreen function and then setting the css would be best.